# Why adding one integer to a function does not cut recursion stack depth in half

Tags: c, pointers, stack-memory

**Edit1:** As advised by some comments, I printed the address of variable.

**Edit2:** As advised by some comments, I added a bit manipulation so that compilers cannot simply throw my variable away

**Edit3:** As advised by one answer, I revised the way a variable's is printed.

**Edit4:** Added quite a bit of non-sense to make life difficult for gcc

**Edit5:** Add a snippet three to test @4386427's theory--the result looks to support his thought that a compiler may reserve 32 Bytes by default. Therefore, we may need to define at least 5 variable to see the difference.

I have some basic understanding of stack memory and heap memory. Take C as an example, if I define a local variable in a function, it occupies stack memory; if I define a pointer and allocate a few memory blocks to it, these memory blocks occupy heap memory. If a function calls itself recursively, the stack will be full and overflow will occur. So I did a simple test and the only difference between snippets one and two is that snippet two has one more integer defined:

**snippet one:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int function(int depth) {
  int tmp = rand() % 65536;
  tmp = tmp - 1;
  printf("val: %d; addr: %p; depth: %d\n", tmp, (void*)&tmp, depth);
  tmp = function(++depth) + 1;
  return tmp;
}
int main() {
  srand(time(NULL));
  int res = function(0);
  printf("%d\n", res);
  return 0;
}
```

**output one:**

```
...
val: 57227; addr: 0x7fff00dff78c; depth: 174626
val: 8288; addr: 0x7fff00dff75c; depth: 174627
val: 24194; addr: 0x7fff00dff72c; depth: 174628
Segmentation fault
```

**snippet two:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int function(int depth) {
  int tmp0 = rand() % 65536;
  int tmp1 = rand() % 65536;
  tmp0 = tmp0 - 1;
  printf("val: %d, %d; addr: %p, %p; depth: %d\n", tmp0, tmp1, (void*)&tmp0, (void*)&tmp1, depth);
  tmp1 = function(++depth);
  return tmp1 - tmp0;
}
int main() {
  srand(time(NULL));
  int res = function(0);
  printf("%d\n", res);
  return 0;
}
```

**output two:**

```
...
val: 40745, 32446; addr: 0x7ffcb80b079c, 0x7ffcb80b0798; depth: 174528
val: 34014, 57470; addr: 0x7ffcb80b076c, 0x7ffcb80b0768; depth: 174529
val: 56801, 34478; addr: 0x7ffcb80b073c, 0x7ffcb80b0738; depth: 174530
Segmentation fault
```

I compiled both code using gcc and as expected both of them cause stack overflow. However, what I initially expected is that the depth of snippet two will be much shallower given that function in snippet two uses 2x memory. However, while snippet two does segfault a bit earlier, the depth of two stacks are actually very close...

If everything works as my naive theory, function in snippet one calls itself 174,616 times, it needs to occupy 4 Bytes * 174,616 / 1,024 = 682 KBytes; function in snippet two calls itself 174,539 times, it need to occupy (4 + 4) Bytes * 174,539 = 1,363 KBytes.

So why is it like this?

**snippet three**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int function(int depth) {
  int tmp0 = rand() % 65536;
  int tmp1 = rand() % 65536;
  int tmp2 = rand() % 65536;
  int tmp3 = rand() % 65536;
  int tmp4 = rand() % 65536;
  int tmp5 = rand() % 65536;
  tmp0 = tmp0 - 1;
  tmp1 = tmp1 + 1;
  tmp2 = tmp2 - 2;
  tmp3 = tmp3 + 2;
  tmp4 = tmp4 - 3;
  tmp5 = tmp5 + 3;
  printf("val: %d, %d, %d; addr: %p, %p, %p; depth: %d\n", tmp0, tmp1, tmp2, (void*)&tmp0, (void*)&tmp1, (void*)&tmp2, depth);
  tmp1 = function(++depth);
  return tmp0 - tmp1 + tmp2 - tmp3 + tmp4;
}
int main() {
  srand(time(NULL));
  long res = function(0);
  printf("%d\n", res);
  return 0;
}
```

**output three**

```
val: 9366, 56113, 48970; addr: 0x7fff063fe830, 0x7fff063fe82c, 0x7fff063fe828; depth: 130920
val: 11924, 11633, 26004; addr: 0x7fff063fe7f0, 0x7fff063fe7ec, 0x7fff063fe7e8; depth: 130921
val: 13316, 42397, 45027; addr: 0x7fff063fe7b0, 0x7fff063fe7ac, 0x7fff063fe7a8; depth: 130922
val: 4285, 58053, 21693; addr: 0x7fff063fe770, 0x7fff063fe76c, 0x7fff063fe768; depth: 130923
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: The compiler may be optimizing the `tmp` vars away making the 2 functions the same.

Comment: This is not a bad experiment, but like any experiment involving rampantly compiler- and processor-dependent behavior such as this, you're probably not going to get crystal-clean, predictable results. :-)  Try also doing `printf(%p\n", &tmp);` during each call — the progression of those addresses will give you a good estimate of the stack frame size.

Comment: Yes I also thought about compiler's optimization--so I did not use a static variable and use random number generator instead...but yes, let me print their address to be very sure.

Comment: Hi @4386427 just tried, with O2 I will still get one. But perhaps your comment is based on some previous versions of the code which were much easier for a compiler to optimize.

Comment: @Mamsds With your first code version and `gcc -O2` the compiler optimized the recursive call and reused the stack frame. The code you have now is **not** tail recursion. Still a clever compiler may figure out that you never reach the `return`.

Comment: @4386427, but if a compiler is so smart, instead of compiling the code that is doomed to crash, it should just tell me: "error: stack overflow detected" instead lol.

Comment: @Mamsds I'm not sure that would be standard compliant. It would really change the observable behavior... rigth? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So why is it like this?

Well, what you describe is in principle correct but... You are forgetting compiler optimization. The compiler is allowed to do all kind of optimizations as long as it doesn't change the observable behavior of your program.

For instance the compiler could decide to keep all your `tmp` variables in cpu registers. In that case there would be no stack memory assigned to them.

You can try to force them to memory by printing their address like:

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)&tmp);
```

Another thing that may happen is that the compiler changes the stack pointer with the same amount for both functions. On my system the compiler reserves 32 bytes in both cases. I had to use 5 `tmp` variables before the compiler change it to 48. In other words - don't expect that the function reserves exactly what it needs. It is allowed to reserve more. On my system it seems that it always change the stack pointer by N x 16.

To get a better understanding, you need to look at the generated machine code. For that you can use `gcc -S`

You can also check this https://godbolt.org/z/x5c3bj7M9

Both function starts with:

```
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 32   <------ Stack pointer change, i.e. reserving memory
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], edi
```

so they use the same amount of stack for both calls.

Same code compiled with `-O2` gives a completely different result https://godbolt.org/z/f6jMEqaPd

The first function gives:

```
    push    rbx
    mov     ebx, edi
    sub     rsp, 48   <------ Stack pointer change, i.e. reserving memory
```

but the second gives:

```
    push    rbx
    mov     ebx, edi
    sub     rsp, 16   <------ Stack pointer change, i.e. reserving memory
```

The conclusion is: You can't just look at the C code and figure out what will happen. You need the machine code.

Comment: The machine code is a bit beyond my level lol...but as shown in the third result, by defining 5 variables, the level of recursion does reduce significantly.

Comment: @Mamsds Look for the changes to `rsp`.

Comment: I vaguely know that RSP is a general purpose register, but I have no idea what exactly does it mean and what is the implication of two versions of the machine code...

Comment: @Mamsds `sub     rsp, 48` means that 48 bytes are reserved on the stack for the current function call

Answer (score 1):

Another smaller expriment:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void function(int depth) {
  if (depth==0) return;
  int tmp = 65536;
  printf("%p\n",&tmp);
  function(--depth);
}
void function2(int depth) {
  if (depth==0) return;
  int tmp = 65536;
  int tmp2 = 65536;
  printf("%p %p\n",&tmp,&tmp2);
  function2(--depth);
}
int main() {
  function(2);
  function2(2);
  return 0;
}
```

can produce the following:

```
0x7ffee80f0988
0x7ffee80f0968
0x7ffee80f0988 0x7ffee80f0984
0x7ffee80f0968 0x7ffee80f0964
```

where one can observe that distance between two local variables each in its own invocation is the same for both functions. That probably means that in these cases stack allocation is of constant size and of the same size in both. If you add more local variables in the second case (4/5) that will change. Stack frame is probably allocated in a size rounded to some value.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned by @4386427, perhaps gcc reserves 32KBytes (i.e., 4 integers) by default. I added a third snippet whose result looks more reasonable.

Comment: @Mamsds Not 32**K**Bytes - just 32 bytes. But again... it all depends on compiler, compiler version, compiler flags... Don't make general conclusions

Comment: Exactly the same I saw when looking at gcc -O0 generated code

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that local variables aren't the only thing stored on the stack.  There are also parameters and the calling function's return address.  So you're more likely looking at a 16 byte vs. 20 byte difference at a minimum rather than 4 vs. 8.

If you look closely at the addresses printed between each iteration, you'll see that they differ by 48 bytes in both cases, so given than it makes sense the stack frame tops out at around the same time.

So it seems the compiler is inserting some padding as well which ends up being taken up by the extra variable in the latter case.

Comment: If it is 16 vs 20 or 160,000 calls vs 200,000 calls, I think it is reasonable enough. However, as the result shows, it is 174,628 vs 174,530. So the difference is basically negligible.